# Gradle not able to run unit tests with Java 17

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, java-17

When trying to use **Java 17** with **Kotlin** I'm having the following issue when trying to run tests. It seems that test classes are compiled with **Java 17** but **Gradle** is trying to run those with **Java 11**. The project is a simple one it is generated using [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/)

```
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.TestSuiteExecutionException: Could not execute test class 'com.test.auth.AuthApplicationTests'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:53)
    at java.base@11.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@11.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base@11.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/test/auth/AuthApplicationTests has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.loadClass(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.access$100(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.execute(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:89)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.execute(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    ... 18 more
```

This is how `build.gradle.kts` looks like:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
  id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.6.2"
  id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
  kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10"
  kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.10"
}

group = "com.test"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
  implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
  implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
  developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
  testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
  testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
  testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
  kotlinOptions {
    freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
    jvmTarget = "17"
  }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

This is the test file that fails:

```
package com.test.auth

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest

@SpringBootTest
class AuthApplicationTests {

  @Test
  fun contextLoads() {
  }

}
```

I kind of have all the environment variables set correctly. `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` both are set correctly to version 17.

Comment: As far as I remember Gradle starts a daemon process in background. If this daemon process was started I am not sure if gradle is able to detect and restart the daemon using Java 17. Therefore I would recommend to kill that daemon nd retry. Also make sure `java` in PATH does not point to an old version.

Comment: [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150978/robert) tried but didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was solved after adding the following config in the tests.

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    val javaToolchains = project.extensions.getByType<JavaToolchainService>()
    javaLauncher.set(javaToolchains.launcherFor {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
    })
}
```

After going through JetBrains documentation regarding [Gradle JVM toolchain support in the Kotlin plugin](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/11/gradle-jvm-toolchain-support-in-the-kotlin-plugin/). Using this based on a specification, Gradle detects a locally installed JDK or JRE or downloads a requested one. Adding the following configurations solved the problem for the tests.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [toolchain](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/11/gradle-jvm-toolchain-support-in-the-kotlin-plugin/) for JVM target configuration (instead of `java.sourceCompatibility` and `kotlinOptions.jvmTarget`). This will make your build independent of JVM version running Gradle itself:

```
kotlin {
    jvmToolchain {
        (this as JavaToolchainSpec).languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
    }
}
```

Comment: [Михаил Нафталь](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13968673/%d0%9c%d0%b8%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%84%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c) getting following error `The new Java toolchain feature cannot be used at the project level in combination with source and/or target compatibility`